# Create GeoTIFF from TIFF using Java

Tags: java, geotiff-tiff

Using Java, I want to add geo tags to existing TIFF file and make it into a GeoTIFF file. Otherwise, for buffered image is it possible to add geotags to make a GeoTIFF file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use java library: [GeoTiff-JAI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geotiff-jai/).

More is in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716462/how-can-i-write-a-geotiff-in-java

Comment: I have tried the  following code:IIOMetadata streamMetadata = reader.getStreamMetadata();
 writer.prepareWriteSequence(streamMetadata);
for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
 bimage = (BufferedImage) bufferedImageList.get(i);
td = TIFFDirectory.createFromMetadata((IIOMetadata)imageMetaDataList.get(i));td.addTIFFField(tf);
iiomage=new IIOImage(bimage, null, td.getAsMetadata());
writer.writeToSequence(iiomage, getParam()); }                 But tag names are not coming as i gave in TiffField?Do you have any idea regarding this?Is any other way exists,if yes please give code snippet